# Does it follow that $F^{(1)}(z)=F^{(2)}(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb H$?

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables, functional-equations, analytic-functions, meromorphic-functions

Let $\mathbb H= \{z \in \mathbb C\,:\, \textrm{Re}\,(z)\geq 0\}$ and for $j=1,2$ suppose that $F^{(j)}:\mathbb H\to \mathbb H$ is defined via
$$ F^{(j)}(z) = \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{a_k^{(j)}}{z+\lambda^{(j)}_k},$$
where $|a_{k}^{(j)}|\leq k^{-2}$ and $0<\lambda^{(j)}_1<\lambda^{(j)}_2<...$ with $\lim_{k\to \infty} \lambda^{(j)}_k=\infty$. Suppose that
$$ F^{(1)}(n)=F^{(2)}(n)\quad \text{for all $n \in \mathbb N$}.$$
Does it follow that $F^{(1)}(z)=F^{(2)}(z)$ for all $z \in \mathbb H$?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is positive. Indeed, $f=F^{(1)}-F^{(2)}$ is a bounded analytic function in the right half-plane (this follows from your conditions $|a_k|\leq k^{-2}$ and $\lambda_k\to\infty$). But a bounded analytic function cannot
be zero at positive integers, unless it is identically equal to zero.
This follows from the [Blaschke condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blaschke_product) on zeros of bounded analytic functions.

Your assumption that $F$ maps the right half-plane into itself is redundant, and the assumption that $\lambda_k>0$ can be very much relaxed; all you need is that your functions are bounded in the right half-plane.

Comment: You probably mean $\lambda_k>0$?